# How to get different colors for every column in a stacked column chart

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, highcharts

I'm trying to do a stacked percentage column chart, however I'm stuck with the layout.

The first picture below shows what I'm trying to achieve with different colors for every column.

[image: Highcharts]

[image]
The second picture above shows the chart that I managed to do.

Comment: Well I'm actually using a plugin for CakePHP to do this chart (https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-highcharts).

But I've used the same logic as in this example :
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent

I've tried to find an example of this being done but so far I haven't found one.

Comment: so, what's the actual question?

Comment: How can I get the columns in color and I also would like to know if it's possible to just change one of the labels color (the 17% one in the first picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the color of each individual bar like so: `{y: 30, color:'green'}`. This is the same in a non-3D graph as it is a 3D graph except that when it's 3D, it colors the entire bar so you lose that distinguishing shading on the top and side. It looks better just to have it non-3D in my opinion.

But anyway, I created what you were hoping for:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                viewDistance: 30,
                depth: 40
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        },
        yAxis: {
           labels: {
              formatter: function(){
                return 100 * this.value / $(this.axis.tickPositions).last()[0] + '%';
              }
           }
        },
        legend:{
            enabled:false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                depth:30,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
           index: 1,
           data: [
                 {y: 30, color:'green'},
                 {y: 20, color: 'blue'},
                 {y: 18, color: 'red'}, 
                 {y: 17, color: 'black'}
              ]
           }, {
             index: 2,
             data: [
                {y: 70, color:'lightgreen'},
                {y: 80, color: 'lightblue'},
                {y: 82, color: 'pink'}, 
                {y: 83, color: 'lightgray'}
             ]
         }]
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/9b0rnr1a/)